# ITMS 90101 error uploading app

Tags: ios, build, upload

I am trying to upload an update for my app to the app store but am met with this error

> ERROR ITMS-90101: "This bundle does not support one or more of the
>   devices supported by the previous app version. Your app update must
>   continue to support all devices previously supported. You declare
>   supported devices in Xcode with the Targeted Device Family build
>   setting. Refer to QA1623 for additional information:
>   https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1623/_index.html"

I have been struggling with this for a while all the info.plist and build settings options are the same the only things that have changed are that i have had to set enable bitcode to NO and let app transport security settings to allow arbitrary loads.

What could be causing this error, is related to the bitcode/arbitrary loads.

EDIT:

I changed settings from iPhone to universal I then get these errors

> ERROR ITMS-90474: "Invalid Bundle. iPad Multitasking support requires
>   these orientations:
>   'UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait,UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown,UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft,UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight'.
>   Found 'UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait' in bundle 'app.app.app'."
>
> ERROR ITMS-90475: "Invalid Bundle. iPad Multitasking support requires
>   launch story board in bundle 'app.app.app'."

I was wondering if these wouldn't appear if the app supported iPads before

Comment: Was your app Universal and now it is either iPhone-only or iPad-only?

Comment: @rmaddy It was iPhone only before and it still is now. I even tried setting it to universal and then changing back still no luck

Comment: The message is about Targeted Device Family. That's referring to iPhone-only, iPad-only, or Universal. And saying you are now supporting less devices can only mean your app was Universal and now it's not. This is covered in the link you posted in your question.

Comment: @rmaddy I have tried changing to universal and updated the post with new errors

Comment: First, you need to confirm what device family the current version of your app supports. Look in iTunes Connect. It will tell you if you look in the right spot. As for the new errors when changing to Universal, unless you haven't updated your app in a long time, it probably means your app has always been an iPhone-only app.

Comment: @rmaddy So it seems that the app was deigned for iphone and ipad and compatible with iphone and ipad and ipod. So i guess that means it was universal.

Comment: But what does it actually show for "Device Family" in iTunes Connect for the specific binary in the app store? You'll see "iPhone / iPod touch", "iPad", or both.

Comment: @rmaddy   iPhone / iPod touch, iPad for device family.

Comment: Yep, it is currently Universal for sure then. And you need to keep it that way. So now you need to fix those other errors and make sure your app properly runs on the full sized screen of iPads in addition to all iPhone sizes.

Answer (score 10):

if your app had already supported iPad and iPhone version for previous submission, but you want to send app uncheck iPad target divece. You can see this error.

Apple doesn't allow your update if you want to unsupported some old devices(only iPad or iphone).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Just create another storyboard name Ipad and change the  Main interface for story board to Ipad.storyboard copy and paste all controller in Main.storyboard and paste it to the Ipad.storyboard and make sure you tick all device orientation for ipad Target setting

**let me make things clear** :-
 1. Create a new duplicate storyboard named

> ***ipad.storyboard***

2. Changes in project setting **General > under deployment**

> **change Device to ipad**

3. change main interface for ipad as the new storyboard

> **ipad.storyboard**

4. Device Orientation

> **tick all**

5. change back the Devices Setting to **Universal** (or else you will recieved a 255 error)

Now you ipad interface will follow the ipad.storyboard views instead of Main.storyboard make sure both storyboard are same at all time.

I hope your problem is solve. 
can email direct for help **cruzvebration35@gmail.com**

Answer (score 2):

If using `expo`, check `app.json`. In my case, i needed to add `"supportsTablet": true`. Also check `"orientation": "portrait"` property.

Answer (score 1):

If you have any missing devices on "Supported Destinations" then add by click plus icon like selected device

[image: Check if you have any missing device then add like selected device]